# How to integrate drupal with sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have drupal 7 and sugar crm 6.5.12 on my system. I want integration between these two system.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal7 and sugarcrm Integration

1) sso integration
2) LDAP
3) SOAP
4) REST
5) oauth

what type of your requirment

there is module Webform2Sugar help to capture lead

Comment: can you tell me the steps

Comment: what steps looking for, decide which level of integration u looking for